# If you're going to be querying on every field in the table, should you index every field?

Tags: mysql, database

Suppose you'll query them the same amount, a LOT.

Comment: Do you mean using every field in the `WHERE` clause, or merely fetching every field?

Comment: It still depends on your actual queries and your actual data. There's no generic answer.

Comment: As @Dan says - it depends on your data. For example, if a certain field will only ever store two values, there's no point in making it an index.

Comment: with this little context: No, not every field and the advice might differ from rdbms to rdbms. Things to try: For each field do a select [field], count(*) from table group by [field]. Index those fields that have an even distribution but still return a reasonable amount of rows (don't index a boolean field). analyze the queries, find out if two or more fields are always used together. Those fields are candidate for a compound index. Have a profiler attached, pick the worst performing query, optimize that one, run again with the profiler, pick the worst performing query, optimize that one...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could, but indexes follow the law of diminishing returns: the more you create and the more data you have, the worse their performance becomes. The perf of your indexes will also depend greatly upon your specific indexing algorithm and whether or not it's appropriate for the amount of data you have stored.

But, in practice, it's always best to index what you need. So, if you **need** to index every field, go ahead and index every field. Like I said though, you'll want to keep an eye on performance of your indexes.

Comment: Youll need to consider the insert performance too - more indexes mean slower inserts.